# Migrating from WCF Data Services to WebApiOdata

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services, edmx, asp.net-web-api-odata

We are currently looking at migrating from WCF Data Services to WebApiOData. The problem that I see is that we have to create a method within a webApi controller for every single table/view that we have that we need to query from the client. The entity model is defined in an edmx with quite a few tables. Having one standard odata.svc that just allowed us to add a table to the edmx and just query it straight through the odata.svc was gold, having to add a method every time we add a view or table to the edmx will be a nightmare and if we are talking about > 50 tables/views it will just turn into a mess of methods everywhere.

Is there a simpler strategy for just having one controller that defines a global get method that we can just query on for all tables/views in the edmx? Or am I needing to create methods for everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESTier](http://odata.github.io/RESTier/) is a layer of abstraction over Web API OData that should feel similar in ways to WCF Data Services, but still allow the flexibility of Web API OData. It already has an EF provider so ideally you should be up and running within minutes with a very small amount of code. Whether it works or doesn't work, we'd love to hear about your experience either in the comments on the GitHub pages or at odatafeedback@microsoft.com.

Comment: Pasting the getting started guidance for @Raven's convenience: http://odata.github.io/RESTier/